# In-line CSS on Form

Tags: css, wordpress, forms

I am having an issue getting my submission forms on my .wysija ((Mail Poet)) forms to line up correctly. I would prefer them to be bumped up beside the top part of the form, but for now, I am settling for just the entry fields being lined up on one line. See images below. Any help is much appreciated!!

((I am on wordpress.org with a .com))

[This is what it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRIbo.png)

[This is the coding that I currently have for the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCDpm.png)

Comment: Can you apply CSS to the parent element of those 3 elements?

Comment: Or try removing `float: left`, change `display: block` to `display: inline-block` and add `vertical-align: middle`. It would really help us if you can provide the code that would replicate what you have and show us what you can change.

Comment: If it helps, my site is www.themommyhoodmoments.com

Comment: I tried adding the vertical align and it didn't change it.

Comment: you can add `p.wysija-paragraph {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}` but your form validation messes it up.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```css
.main-block{
width:600px;
padding:25px;
}
.name{
width:200px;
float:left;
margin-right:15px;
}
.email{
width:200px;
float:left;
margin-right:15px;
}
.btn{
width:50px;
float:left;
margin-right:15px;
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <div class="name"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name here."></div>
  <div class="email"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email here."></div>
  <div class="btn"><input type="submit" class="btn"></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```